# Pandas dataframe with datetimeindex, sorting records by month and then year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, linear-regression

I have a problem with pandas dataframe **indexed with datetime** values, my dataframe `temps` looks like this:

```
                 column      column
Index        | land_temps | ocean_temps
1861-01-01   |     -5     |    15
1861-02-01   |      0     |    17
1861-03-01   |      6     |    18
                   .
                   .
                   .
2015-11-01   |      2     |    17
2015-12-01   |     -1     |    14
```

So to sum up, I have a pandas dataframe with date as datatimeindexes, and floats (temperatures) as columns.
I would like to sort rekords of this dataframe by monts of measurement, to achieve sth like this :

```
Index        | land_temps | ocean_temps
1861-01-01   |     -5     |    15
1862-02-01   |     -4     |    13
1863-03-01   |     -6     |    14
                   .
                   .
                   .
2014-12-01   |     -2     |    13
2015-12-01   |     -1     |    14
```

How to do that? I have tried:

```
temps.sort_values(by=temps.index.month, axis='index')
```

but it does not work like that I guess, so is there any way to do thay using build in sorting/groupby panadas methods (or similar).

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Is your index datetimeindex? Or still object(string)?

Comment: It is datetimeindex, sorry for not highlighting that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two additional columns (you can drop them later) and then you can sort according to those columns

```
temps['month'] = temps.index.month
temps['year'] = temps.index.year
temps.sort_values(['month', 'year']).drop(columns=['month', 'year'])
```